# How to make JavaScript array values as variables for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops

Why second FOR loop don't work ?

```
toget = new Array("var18", "var4", "var43");

for (var i=0; i < toget.length; i++) {

    for (var x=0; x < result.toget[i].list.length; x++) {
    alert(x);
    }

}
```

If I do like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < toget.length; i++) {

    for (var x=0; x < result.var18.list.length; x++) {
    alert(x);
    }

}
```

It works but this is not correct way.

I need that values in toget array become variables to process them in second FOR loop.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify what "result" is?

Comment: "result.var18.list.length" is what?

Comment: Your code is missing what result is.  Only guessing is possible for an answer until you include all relevant code.

Comment: what is "result"? and better yet, why is this tagged as jquery?

Comment: ... where and how is jQuery coming into play here?

Comment: `result.toget[i]`.  This is getting the property `i` from `result.toget`.  You want to get the property `toget[i]` from `result`, so it should be `result[toget[i]]`.

Comment: result is another array and toget[i] is just key names of that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < toget.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < result[toget[i]].list.length; x++) {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery `each` loop even better than `for` loop

```
toget = new Array("var18", "var4", "var43");

$.each(toget, function(i){
    $.each(result[toget[i]].list, function(x){
      alert(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: `result.toget[i].list` is incorrect here.  It should be `result[toget[i]].list`.

Comment: I didn't know about the $.each() function.  It looks very useful to me.

Comment: Yes, it is very useful take a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)